# What's happening when I try a search on the number of comments?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments

I wanted to see articles that had no comments and no answers.  I did [this search](https://superuser.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=comments%3a0%20answers%3a0) and some of the results that came up had some comments.  The question that had comments was [How to make a busy file not busy so it can be deleted. rm: filename: Resource busy](https://superuser.com/questions/1068175).

Should I expect this kind of search to work?  Is there a work-around?

Comment: I just realised I hadn't checked how searches using more than one keyword/colon/number work.  Maybe there's an implied 'or' rather than an implied 'and'.  I'll investigate.

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), since `comments` does not appear to be an actual search operator. We can see this by looking in the upper-right of the search results, where it shows the interpretation of your search terms:

[image: literal comments:0]

"Zero answers" is a search criterion, but it's looking for the literal `comments:0` string in posts. As far as I know, the on-site search doesn't know anything about comments, unfortunately.

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE), on the other hand, does know about comments. You can use [this little query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/edit/659086#resultSets) I wrote. Note that SEDE isn't continually updated, so there are a handful of questions in there that had activity between the data update and now.

Comment: Great to learn of SEDE, thank you Ben!